# How does the reset button function in Xcode 7's signing identities dialog window

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I can archive my application with my code signing identities and provisioning profile for distribution.  And the binary created can be validated successfully.

However it bothers me that Xcode 7 shows a reset button besides the iOS distribution option in the signing identity dialog.

[image]

How does the reset button function?

Should I press the button to reset my signing identity accordingly or just ignore it since I can archive without error messages?

Some guess:

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

> #### Resetting Certificates Using Xcode
>
> If Xcode detects an issue with a signing identity, it displays an appropriate action in Accounts preferences. If Xcode displays a Create button, the signing identity doesn’t exist in Member Center or on your Mac. If Xcode displays a Reset button, the signing identity is not usable on your Mac—for example, it is missing the private key. If you click the Reset button, Xcode revokes and re-creates the corresponding certificate.

In my keychain there are two certificate, one of which with missing private key.  I guess that xcode 7 might detect the one with missing private key and thus kept showing me the reset button.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33814665/1633251

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same behavior when I have multiple certificates with the same name but different expiration dates.  In this case, tapping the "Reset" button disables the button for the current session of the dialog, but nothing seems to happen with regard to revoke/reissue of certificate(s).

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment on the post. It's relatively obvious the button is disabled for the remainder of the dialog being open, but what the OP wants to know is...what did that do?