# How can I reset or recreate iOS Distribution Signing Identity

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I'm trying to install a signed iOS Enterprise app and I'm getting an error on installing 'Unable to Download Application - “APP” could not be downloaded at this time'

The app seems to be downloaded properly, I thought it might be a provisioning profile error or something like that. The only thing I came across was a 'reset' button next to my iOS Distribution signing identity.

I came across the Apple docs here, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW16 in the 'Resetting Certificates Using Xcode' section and tried the 'Reset' button but it doesn't seem to do anything. When I click 'Done' and come back into this screen I'm seeing the same reset button.

Has anyone else come across this? I've spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.

[image: Developer Account Signing Identities]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that sounds like what's going on with your install. I wouldn't trust the whatever you're using to reload your certs. Try it manually.

A few things to check:

- Ensure that the certificate is installed on your machine.
- Ensure that the device that you're installing the application on has been   added to your list of devices.
- Ensure that your provisioning profile contains your device from the list of devices.
- Lastly ensure that the provisioning profile has been installed on your machine.

Rather than resetting your certificates using the GUI just crack open the terminal and do the following:

- Go to: $~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
- Remove all certs: $rm -rf *
- Reinstall your certs

I normally run into this issue. Sometimes the certs fail to update once I reinstall them so I just remove them all. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I tried your manual suggestion to remove the provisioning profiles and reload them. After I removed them, I clicked on the 'reset' button and it downloaded everything. I also found an issue with the plist file I deployed with my ipa file (Enterprise deployment needs this file) and found a small typo which I suspect was part of my problem. I'll award you the answer because even if it wasn't the route of my issue, I learned something new I could do to refresh the certs. I was always afraid I was going to mess something up deleting those.